# Face recognition can't install

Tags: python, cmd, pip, face-recognition

The command used for installing face-recognition is `pip install` `face-recognition` for python version 3.8.3

**ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'd:\program files\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tfxpway5\dlib\setup.py'"'"'**;

```
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tfxpway5\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nid980qb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'd:\program files\python\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tfxpway5\dlib\
    Complete output (57 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tfxpway5\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tfxpway5\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=d:\program files\python\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tfxpway5\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.18363.
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
      No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
      No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/Elias/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-tfxpway5/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/Elias/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-tfxpway5/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tfxpway5\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "d:\program files\python\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "d:\program files\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "d:\program files\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "d:\program files\python\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "d:\program files\python\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "d:\program files\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "d:\program files\python\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "d:\program files\python\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "d:\program files\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tfxpway5\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tfxpway5\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "d:\program files\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tfxpway5\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tfxpway5\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=d:\\program files\\python\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tfxpway5\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\program files\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tfxpway5\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tfxpway5\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nid980qb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'd:\program files\python\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Windows is not officially supported (https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/#installing-on-windows), so you can't just install it directly with pip. See this GH issue for the workaround: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/175

Comment: Are you using anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

You might try deepface package for python.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace

#this compares img1 and img2 are same person or not (face verification)
result  = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg")

#this will look for the identity of img1 in the my_db folder (face recognition)
df = DeepFace.find(img_path = "img1.jpg", db_path = "C:/workspace/my_db")
```